# css 3-coloured linear gradient with sharp colour boundaries

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

Is this possible to achive with linear-gradient? For example, I can do a 2-coloured gradient (red,green) at any ratio with a colour stop, e.g. the below is 30% red, 70% green.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, red 30%, green 30%);
```

Is it possible to do 3 colours at a given ratio?

Comment: just do the same trick on the 60% boundary

Comment: Thanks! That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, red 30%, green 30%, green 60%, blue 60%)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6fn3q9t6/)

Comment: jsfiddle link is broken (missing a "d")

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) you can specify as many colors as you want with the proportions as percentage.See the following rainbow example where red color takes 50%:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, orange, yellow, green, blue, 
indigo, violet);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/21fsxz2j/1/)

Comment: Yes but all the other colours, apart from red, transition into each other. I'd like to know if it's possible to have sharp colour stops between all the colours so in a sense you end up with a 3-coloured background.